# What is Double Zero Grade?

Tags: terminology, morphology, proto-indo-european, morphosyntax

> The double zero grade **ǵʰi-m-* is preserved in the compounds with numerals.

(de Vaan, Etymological Dictionary of Latin 2013: *hiems*)

E.g. **dwi-ǵʰim-os* *“two years old”, literally “of two winters”* (en.Wiktionary: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/%C7%B5%CA%B0%C3%A9y%C5%8Dm)

> Unbelebtes **h<sub>1</sub>ésu-∅* kann zwar durch gr. εὖ, nicht aber durch altheth. *šu* oder ved. *śu* fortgesetzt werden, d.h. das Adverb **h<sub>1</sub>sú-∅* stellt keine erstarrte Kasusform dar. Vielmehr wurde es von der Komposition her, wo die Doppelnullstufe eines nominalen Vorderglieds durchaus am Platz ist (s. **du(-s-)* Fn. 18), verallgemeinert.

(Dunkel, Lexikon der indogermanischen Partikeln und Pronominalstämme, Bd. 1, p. 305)

In short, Dunkel says **h<sub>1</sub>sú-∅* was generalized as **h<sub>1</sub>ésu-∅* from the **double zero grade** of *some* (“eines”) noun prefix.

If I understand correctly, this means that **dwi* is zero grade, **ǵʰi-m-* is zero grade, so the compound is double that. The parallel in Dunkel's notation **-∅* makes that very clear.

I just don't understand the implication, because it is usually enough to point out the single zero grade and the evidence for it.

- Double zero grade in numeral compounds may be ominous, as if the full grade might be derived from metanalysis of a consonant cluster as zero grade in one of those words, requiring an alternative etymology for it, but there is no indication of that.

  - De Vaan's bracketing **-m-* is obvious, not to me though.
- Dunkel's analysis doesn't profit from double zero grade. I don't have a full copy, but there is no obvious reason that the zero grade would occur first in double zero grade.

  - FYI, note that Wiktionary lists **h<sub>1</sub>su-* as uncertain under **h<sub>1</sub>es-* and offers an alternative explanation from **h<sub>1</sub>wes-*.

Am I missing something? I am hesitantly not posting this as a reference request because I don't believe it is a thing. Convince me I am wrong.

---

Following @Janus' comment, **-m-* is zero grade of the Genetive suffix, full-grade **-ém-, o-grade **-ōm-.

But still,  this seems diametrical opposed to Dunkel saying that "**h<sub>1</sub>sú-∅* stellt keine erstarrte Kasusform dar", precisely not fossilized in case form.

Comment: De Vaan is saying that _*g̑ʰi-m-_ is a double zero grade in itself, without even considering the form of the numeral: he takes the base form as being nom. _*g̑ʰei̯-ōm_ (full-grade root, long o-grade suffix), acc. _*g̑ʰi-ém-m̥_ (zero-grade root, full-grade suffix), gen. _*g̑ʰi-m-ós_ (zero-grade root, zero-grade suffix = double zero grade). The double zero grade found in the PIE genitive was lost in the inflectional paradigm of the base word in Latin, where the zero-grade/full-grade combination was generalised from the accusative, but it survived in compounds with numerals.

Comment: As for the Dunkel quote, I’m not sure I quite follow his implications either, but as best I can tell, he’s assuming that _*h₁su-_ is from a combination of _*h₁es-_ + _*-eu̯-_ (≈ a _u_-stem to _*h₁es-_), and then saying that the adverb _*h₁su_ cannot be a frozen case form of this _u_-stem, because there are no forms in that paradigm that have double zero-grade (in both the root, _*h₁s-_, and the suffix, _*-u-_) and no overt case ending. Therefore, he says, the standalone adverb must be extracted from compounds with the stress on the head noun, where _*h₁s-u-CV́-_ is just what we’d expect.

Answer (score -2):

German seems to use different terms for *Schwundstufe* and *Nullstufe*, but English uses *zero grade* indiscriminately.